# Spotify API for Android - Retrieving JSON item from paging object

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2, spotify

I'm using the andorid-java wrapper for the spotify api in an app project.

https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android

I'm having a hard time extracting the response from my Spotify API requests. Extracting single responses is easy, but once the response is a paging object, I struggle. How can I print the album titles from "getArtistAlbums" in logcat, just to check if the response is correct?

Here's the code to explain my problem:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void setupSpotifyAPI() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    token = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TOKEN);
    logMessage("Api Client created");
    spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi();
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(token);

    final SpotifyService spotify = spotifyApi.getService();

    spotify.getArtistAlbums("0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg", new SpotifyCallback<Pager<Album>>() {
        @Override
        public void failure(SpotifyError spotifyError) {

        }

        @Override
        public void success(Pager<Album> albumPager, Response response) {

            Log.v("hello", albumPager.items.toString());

        }
    });

}

}
```

For this exact job, the logcat prints this:

```
D/MAIN: Api Client created
08-15 12:48:57.218 20889-21973/applicationname.companydomain.myapplication D/Retrofit: ---> HTTP GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg/albums
08-15 12:48:57.244 20889-20931/applicationname.companydomain.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3d040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3d032d0)
08-15 12:48:57.764 20889-20931/applicationname.companydomain.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3d040c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3d032d0)
08-15 12:48:58.173 20889-21973/applicationname.companydomain.myapplication D/Retrofit: <--- HTTP 200 https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0TnOYISbd1XYRBk9myaseg/albums (953ms)
08-15 12:48:58.225 20889-20889/applicationname.companydomain.myapplication V/hello: [kaaes.spotify.webapi.android.models.Album@833d3be, kaaes.spotify.webapi.android.models.Album@b893c1f, kaaes.spotify.webapi.android.models.Album@8ba3b6c
```

where
    `kaaes.spotify.webapi.android.models.Album@833d3be` 
is just an object, and not metadata.

when using

```
response.getBody().toString()
```

logcat prints this:

```
V/hello: retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient$TypedInputStream@77dfecd
```

How can I go on and get the data I really need, and not only objects?

Please see the the issue I've opened on the github rep:

https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android/issues/169

Comment: Use gson to convert your albumPager.items into json then you can print it on logcat

Comment: Thanks! This also helped :) I definitely can use this for JSON scraping and bigger JSON operations in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply iterate over the pager items.

```
for (Album album : albumPager.items) {
   Log.d("album name", album.name);
}
```